# I want to keep a class changed by jquery across the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this can be done. I'm new on jQuery :)

I have found a way to change a background by clicking an image. But when I refresh the page or change to another page, the background is changed to the original.

Do you know if there is a way to keep the new background selected?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mood-clasico").click(function(){
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").removeClass("parallax-4, parallax-2");
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").addClass("parallax-1");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mood-chef").click(function(){
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").removeClass("parallax-1, parallax-2");
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").addClass("parallax-4");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mood-kids").click(function(){
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").removeClass("parallax-1, parallax-4");
        $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").addClass("parallax-2");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The web is stateless by default, so you need to store a value somewhere in order to read it again. Look into cookies, a database, localStorage, etc.

Comment: Thanks @j08691 I will try with cookies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the state to survive after the window's been closed or page has been navigated away from (to a different domain), use localStorage; otherwise, use sessionStorage (still survives refresh and navigation within the domain).  Either way, you'll want to store the css class in a persistent variable and use that to instead of the string, which can help dry the code up a bit too.
Session storage is a little simpler, but your users would probably love you more for using localStorage -- implementation would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userPref = localStorage.getItem("bg-class") || 'your-default';
  $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto").addClass(userPref);

  $("#mood-clasico").click(function(){
    swapPref("parallax-4", "parallax-2", "parallax-1");
  });
  $("#mood-chef").click(function(){
    swapPref("parallax-1", "parallax-2", "parallax-4");
  });
  $("#mood-kids").click(function(){
    swapPref("parallax-4", "parallax-2", "parallax-1");
  });

  function swapPref(out1, out2, inn) {
    $("#chef, #ranchos, #contacto")
    .removeClass(userPref)
    .removeClass(out1)
    .removeClass(out2)
    .addClass(inn);
    localStorage.setItem("bg-class", inn);
  }
});
```

For more persistence (like across different browsers or devices) you'd want to look into the file system api or storing the settings in a database, but based on your question it doesn't seem those options aren't worth the drawbacks.  I left out some error handling and things you'd probably want to include, but I'd definitely recommend checking out [using the web storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) by mozilla, which actually includes a similar example.

Comment: Many thanks @J.Mett this is working :)   I really appreciated :)  Just a doubt,  it's only working after I refresh the page, is there a way to make the change at the time a click the option? Thanks again :)

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that, I forgot about the initial class added `userPref`, that was never removed.  I made an edit which should work

Comment: Many thanks @J.Mett :D it's working now :) I will review the page you provided to learn more about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery cookie plugin to do this,

details here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

then set cookie,

```
$.cookie("changedBackground", 'true');
```

and after page refresh this check must be done

```
if($.cookie("changedBackground")=='true'){
//keep your changed background
}
```

Answer (score -1):

only with jQuery it's impossible, you have to store the value 
try to use session , cockies , external file or data base

Comment: Thanks @AnonyPIng  will try with cookies :)